# WPF C# XAML ListBox mouse events (right click vs left click)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox, click

I have a `ListBox` dynamically generated.

In this `ListBox` there are some Items that the user could select, one or more, by left click.

With the right click on an Item of the `ListBox` area he could show a context menu.

My problem is that if the user right-clicks in the ListBox area all goes right, but if he right-clicks on an Items he toggles the selection.

I want to avoid the Items toggling by the right click.

This is how I configured the `ListBox` in the `MyWindow.cs`:

```
MyBeautifulList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;
```

And this is a portion of the relative XAML file:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Send file"  Click="SendFileToUser" />
        <MenuItem Header="Send folder" Click="SendFolderToUser" />
        <MenuItem Header="Copy user ID to the clipboard" Click="copyUserIDtoClipboard" />
    </ContextMenu>
 </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as click, wpf offers a bunch of other options.
Due to bubbling and tunnelling routed events which you might want to read up on.
You can handle the preview version of an event, mark it as handled and then it stops it firing.

```
void MenuItem_PreviewRightMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

You will then have no context menu appear, so you will need to show the context menu using code.
Name your context menu

```
<ContextMenu Name="SomeMeaningfulName">
```

You can then set IsOpen in code in your new handler, like:

```
SomeMeaningfulName.IsOpen = true;
```